# Camel Karaf (OSGI Blueprint) SQL datasource

Tags: apache-camel, osgi, datasource, apache-karaf, camel-sql

Hi Guys I'm having some issues with my datasource in Karaf 4.3.6 (recent upgrade) I'm hoping someone could shed some light on what I'm doing wrong here.

**Before the upgrade**

**Karaf had the below services (org.osgi.service.jdbc.DataSourceFactory):**

```
[org.osgi.service.jdbc.DataSourceFactory]
-----------------------------------------
 osgi.jdbc.driver.class = com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
 osgi.jdbc.driver.name = com.microsoft.sqlserver.mssql-jdbc-native
 osgi.jdbc.driver.version = 6.2.2.jre8
 service.bundleid = 46
 service.id = 219
 service.scope = singleton
Provided by :
 Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server (46)

[org.osgi.service.jdbc.DataSourceFactory]
-----------------------------------------
 osgi.jdbc.driver.class = com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
 osgi.jdbc.driver.name = Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server
 osgi.jdbc.driver.version = 7.4
 service.bundleid = 47
 service.id = 223
 service.scope = singleton
Provided by :
 Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server (47)

[org.osgi.service.jdbc.DataSourceFactory]
-----------------------------------------
 osgi.jdbc.driver.class = com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
 osgi.jdbc.driver.name = mssql
 service.bundleid = 157
 service.id = 252
 service.scope = singleton
Provided by :
 OPS4J Pax JDBC MSSQL Driver Adapter (157)
Used by:
 example-project(173)
 OPS4J Pax JDBC Config (38)
```

**My project blueprint contained the below:**

```
    <bean id="sqlComponent" class="org.apache.camel.component.sql.SqlComponent">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="exampleSQLServerDataSource"/>
</bean>

<service id="c1SQLDataSource" interface="javax.sql.DataSource" ref="exampleSQLServerDataSource">
    <service-properties>
        <entry key="osgi.jndi.service.name" value="exSQLDataSource"/>
    </service-properties>
</service>

<bean id="exampleSQLServerDataSource" factory-ref="sqlServerDataSourceFactory" factory-method="createDataSource">
  <argument>
    <props>
      <prop key="databaseName">${ex.db.dbname}</prop>
      <prop key="user">${ex.db.user}</prop>
      <prop key="password">${ex.db.password}</prop>
      <prop key="portNumber">${ex.db.port}</prop>
      <prop key="serverName">${ex.db.host}</prop>
    </props>
  </argument>
</bean>

<reference id="sqlServerDataSourceFactory" interface="org.osgi.service.jdbc.DataSourceFactory" filter="(objectClass=org.osgi.service.jdbc.DataSourceFactory)(osgi.jdbc.driver.name=mssql)"/>
```

With this configuration my project worked fine on install / i could use the camel-sql component with my datasource.

**After the upgrade**

Changes to karaf depensancys meant that the mssql factory was no longer available (even when starting the feature for pax-jdbc-mssql)

**Karaf had the below services (org.osgi.service.jdbc.DataSourceFactory):**

```
[org.osgi.service.jdbc.DataSourceFactory]
-----------------------------------------
 osgi.jdbc.driver.class = com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
 osgi.jdbc.driver.name = com.microsoft.sqlserver.mssql-jdbc-native
 osgi.jdbc.driver.version = 6.2.2.jre8
 service.bundleid = 54
 service.id = 214
 service.scope = singleton
Provided by :
 Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server (54)

[org.osgi.service.jdbc.DataSourceFactory]
-----------------------------------------
 osgi.jdbc.driver.class = com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
 osgi.jdbc.driver.name = Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server
 osgi.jdbc.driver.version = 9.2
 service.bundleid = 55
 service.id = 371
 service.scope = singleton
Provided by :
 Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server (55)

[org.osgi.service.jdbc.DataSourceFactory]
-----------------------------------------
 osgi.jdbc.driver.class = com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
 osgi.jdbc.driver.name = Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server
 osgi.jdbc.driver.version = 9.4
 service.bundleid = 282
 service.id = 370
 service.scope = singleton
Provided by :
 Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server (282)
```

**My project blueprint containes the below:**

I modified my blueprint.xml to use one of the other connections available in jdbc:ds-factories but i am seeing the below error complaining of missing requirements on install

```
<bean id="sqlComponent" class="org.apache.camel.component.sql.SqlComponent">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="exampleSQLServerDataSource"/>
</bean>

<service id="c1SQLDataSource" interface="javax.sql.DataSource" ref="exampleSQLServerDataSource">
    <service-properties>
        <entry key="osgi.jndi.service.name" value="exSQLDataSource"/>
    </service-properties>
</service>

<bean id="exampleSQLServerDataSource" factory-ref="sqlServerDataSourceFactory" factory-method="createDataSource">
  <argument>
    <props>
      <prop key="databaseName">${ex.db.dbname}</prop>
      <prop key="user">${ex.db.user}</prop>
      <prop key="password">${ex.db.password}</prop>
      <prop key="portNumber">${ex.db.port}</prop>
      <prop key="serverName">${ex.db.host}</prop>
    </props>
  </argument>
</bean>

<reference id="sqlServerDataSourceFactory" interface="org.osgi.service.jdbc.DataSourceFactory" filter="(osgi.jdbc.driver.class=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver)(osgi.jdbc.driver.name=Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server)(osgi.jdbc.driver.version=9.4)"/>
```

**Seeing this error on install**

```
karaf@root()> feature:install example-project
org.apache.felix.resolver.reason.ReasonException: Unable to resolve root: missing requirement [root] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=example-project; type=karaf.feature; version="[0.1.4.SNAPSHOT,0.1.4.SNAPSHOT]"; filter:="(&(osgi.identity=example-project)(type=karaf.feature)(version>=0.1.4.SNAPSHOT)(version<=0.1.4.SNAPSHOT))" [caused by: Unable to resolve example-project/0.1.4.SNAPSHOT: missing requirement [example-project/0.1.4.SNAPSHOT] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=com.example.example.project; type=osgi.bundle; version="[0.1.4.SNAPSHOT,0.1.4.SNAPSHOT]"; resolution:=mandatory [caused by: Unable to resolve com.example.example.project/0.1.4.SNAPSHOT: missing requirement [com.example.example.project/0.1.4.SNAPSHOT] osgi.service; effective:=active; filter:="(&(objectClass=org.osgi.service.jdbc.DataSourceFactory)(osgi.jdbc.driver.class=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver)(osgi.jdbc.driver.name=Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server)(osgi.jdbc.driver.version=9.4))"]]
        at org.apache.felix.resolver.Candidates$MissingRequirementError.toException(Candidates.java:1341)
        at org.apache.felix.resolver.ResolverImpl.doResolve(ResolverImpl.java:433)
        at org.apache.felix.resolver.ResolverImpl.resolve(ResolverImpl.java:420)
        at org.apache.felix.resolver.ResolverImpl.resolve(ResolverImpl.java:374)
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.region.SubsystemResolver.resolve(SubsystemResolver.java:257)
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.Deployer.deploy(Deployer.java:399)
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.FeaturesServiceImpl.doProvision(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:1069)
        at org.apache.karaf.features.internal.service.FeaturesServiceImpl.lambda$doProvisionInThread$13(FeaturesServiceImpl.java:1004)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.felix.resolver.reason.ReasonException: Unable to resolve example-project/0.1.4.SNAPSHOT: missing requirement [example-project/0.1.4.SNAPSHOT] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=com.example.example.project; type=osgi.bundle; version="[0.1.4.SNAPSHOT,0.1.4.SNAPSHOT]"; resolution:=mandatory [caused by: Unable to resolve com.example.example.project/0.1.4.SNAPSHOT: missing requirement [com.example.example.project/0.1.4.SNAPSHOT] osgi.service; effective:=active; filter:="(&(objectClass=org.osgi.service.jdbc.DataSourceFactory)(osgi.jdbc.driver.class=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver)(osgi.jdbc.driver.name=Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server)(osgi.jdbc.driver.version=9.4))"]
        at org.apache.felix.resolver.Candidates$MissingRequirementError.toException(Candidates.java:1341)
        ... 12 more
Caused by: org.apache.felix.resolver.reason.ReasonException: Unable to resolve com.example.example.project/0.1.4.SNAPSHOT: missing requirement [com.example.example.project/0.1.4.SNAPSHOT] osgi.service; effective:=active; filter:="(&(objectClass=org.osgi.service.jdbc.DataSourceFactory)(osgi.jdbc.driver.class=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver)(osgi.jdbc.driver.name=Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server)(osgi.jdbc.driver.version=9.4))"
        at org.apache.felix.resolver.Candidates$MissingRequirementError.toException(Candidates.java:1341)
        ... 13 more
Error executing command: Unable to resolve root: missing requirement [root] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=example-project; type=karaf.feature; version="[0.1.4.SNAPSHOT,0.1.4.SNAPSHOT]"; filter:="(&(osgi.identity=example-project)(type=karaf.feature)(version>=0.1.4.SNAPSHOT)(version<=0.1.4.SNAPSHOT))" [caused by: Unable to resolve example-project/0.1.4.SNAPSHOT: missing requirement [example-project/0.1.4.SNAPSHOT] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=com.example.example.project; type=osgi.bundle; version="[0.1.4.SNAPSHOT,0.1.4.SNAPSHOT]"; resolution:=mandatory [caused by: Unable to resolve com.example.example.project/0.1.4.SNAPSHOT: missing requirement [com.example.example.project/0.1.4.SNAPSHOT] osgi.service; effective:=active; filter:="(&(objectClass=org.osgi.service.jdbc.DataSourceFactory)(osgi.jdbc.driver.class=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver)(osgi.jdbc.driver.name=Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server)(osgi.jdbc.driver.version=9.4))"]]
```

**POM**

The **maven-bundle-plugin** definition from my pom.xml file

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <configuration>
            <instructions>
                <Import-Package>
                    javax.jms;version="[2.0,3)",
                    org.xmlsoap.schemas.soap.envelope,
                    com.example.example.services.amqp.*,
                    *
                </Import-Package>
            </instructions>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: First - you have 3 MS SQL Drivers installed. Your blueprint looks fine and should reference the service with ID `370`.
However, the error is produced during bundle resolution and my practice is that bundle resolution and service discovery sometimes cause problems. Blueprint itself is enough to give you service proxy even if the target service is not available (yet).
I'd remove the `Import-Service` and/or `Require-Capability` from your manifest - using maven-bundle-plugin, just add `<_removeheaders>Import-Service</_removeheaders>`

Comment: Hello @GrzegorzGrzybek sorry Im not following what your suggesting, I have included the  maven-bundle-plugin definition from my POM.xml file above, are you able to expand a bit on your suggestion?

If i extract my bundle jar and look and look at the manifest i see the below:

Import-Service: org.osgi.service.jdbc.DataSourceFactory;multiple:=fals
 e;filter=(osgi.jdbc.driver.class=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServ
 erDriver)(osgi.jdbc.driver.name=Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server)

Require-Capability: osgi.ee;filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"
Tool: Bnd-3.3.0.201609221906

Comment: @GrzegorzGrzybek If i modify the manifest and remove the import-services section i still get the same error when installing the feature in karaf.

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading the error message correctly, your Karaf is for some reason missing [SQLServerDataSourceFactory](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-jdbc/blob/v9.4.1/src/main/java/com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/osgi/SQLServerDataSourceFactory.java) service that should be provided by sqlserver [activator](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-jdbc/blob/v9.4.1/src/main/java/com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/osgi/Activator.java#L33) when the bundle starts.

If you're upgrading from Apache Karaf version 4.2.x to 4.3.6 it could be that the [version](https://github.com/ops4j/org.ops4j.pax.jdbc/blob/jdbc-1.5.2/pom.xml#L206) of the `mssql-jdbc/9.4.0.jre8` bundle which the pax-jdbc-mssql feature installs could be incompatible with Java 11.

Apache Karaf 4.3.x supports JDK 11+ where as 4.2.x is for JDK 8, 9 and 10. There's handy table on Apache karafs [downloads page](https://karaf.apache.org/download.html#karaf) that shows which version supports what. [Mail about JDK 8 support with 4.3.x](https://www.mail-archive.com/user@karaf.apache.org/msg23263.html)

Since the feature [pax-jdbc-mssql](https://github.com/ops4j/org.ops4j.pax.jdbc/blob/jdbc-1.5.2/pax-jdbc-features/src/main/resources/features.xml#L117-L121) only contains mssql-jdbc bundle and pax-jdbc-spec feature you could try to install them separately using jre11 version of mssql-jdbc bundle.

**Example:**

```sh
feature:install pax-jdbc-spec
bundle:install mvn:com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc/9.4.1.jre11
```

Since the version 9.4.1 has some vulnerabilities you could also try to upgrade to the newer [10.2.0.jre11](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc/10.2.0.jre11) version if possible.

Comment: Im using Java 8 for karaf / all java and jdk 8 when compiling my project home variables are defined correctly. 

I have tried the same configuration with driver versions 6.2.2.jre8, 9.2, and 9.4 all seem to fail.

Comment: Apache Karaf versions 4.3.0 and above do not support Java 8. There's a handy table on [Apache Karaf download page](https://karaf.apache.org/download.html#karaf) that shows this. Using bundles meant for java 8 with it can lead to unexpected behavior.